# Vector Space with unusual operations

Tags: linear-algebra

In this example, i'm checking to see whether this is a vector space or not.

There is a set $V = \{x \in \Bbb R | x > 0\}$ with the operations $x \oplus y = xy$ and $c \otimes x = x^c$

Axiom 4 states that "There exists a vector 0 $\in \Bbb V$ such that $u \oplus  0 = u$.

In the example that I given, we are checking axiom 4 and it goes like this:
$x \oplus 1 = x(1) = x$
meaning this axiom passes.

How is the zero vector a 1? shouldn't it be $x \oplus 0 = x(0) = 0$ which means this axiom fails and this example is not a vector space? Also, whats the point of unusual operations?

Comment: The zero vector is just *a* vector $\mathbf{v}$ with the property that for all vectors $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{x}\oplus\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{x}$. What it actually is when it is at home is irrelevant. The number $1$ goes to work as the zero vector in this vector space.

Comment: In the axiom $0$ is a notation, $0\in V$. You confuse it with $0\in \mathbb R$, which is the null element for addition

Comment: Note that the real number $0$ is not even an element of your set.

Comment: So basically, in the axioms x + 0 = x, we can treat it the same when it comes to multiplying but instead of multiplying the vector by a zero, we make it a 1? so, x(1) = x?

Comment: The axioms say that it is a vector which when you "vectoradd" it to another vector, it results in the other vector, whatever "vector"  and "vectoradd" mean given the description. Here "vector" means "positive real number" and "vectoradd" means "multiply the real numbers". We call it the zero vector, but what you call it doesn't tell you which real number it is, it just tells you what it does when you vectoradd it to another vector. "Zero vector" is its job title, not its soul.

Comment: Call your zero vector $\vec Z$ to distinguish it from $0 ∈ \mathbb R$.